# Changing color of ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview

First of all, this is the code I use for ListView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/top_layer"
    android:id="@+id/top_layer_Q1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/top_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/Quotelist1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

In order to test the code, I created a temporary project in Studio, and the Output I got was Black text in white background. And when I added the same code to the project I am working, I get the output with a Black Background and white text. 
Though I did not change any code, what might be causing this? What is the best fix for this?

Thanks,

**EDIT1**

Here is the `styles.xml`

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: Please post your styles.xml of your project

Comment: what do you want to change? Divider?

Comment: nope, the background, currently it is black, want it white

Comment: Which API version are you testing it on?

Comment: minSdkVersion :19 , targetSdkVersion:21, compileSdkVersion:21

Comment: Try to change the theme to `"Theme.AppCompat"`

Comment: And how are you inflating the ListView? Are you using custom adapter? Or a regular list adapter?

Comment: @iturki ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Add this to your style.xml

  ```
  <style name="ListStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
      <item name="android:textColor">#FF000000</item>
      <item name="android:background">#FFFFFFFF</item>
  </style>
  ```
- Then set it as the style for your listView

  ```
  style="@style/ListStyle"
  ```

Comment: while running it gives some error, do I need to add anything to `Manifest` ?

Comment: unknown attribute Android:style, while adding `android:style="@style/ListStyle"` to XML , I am using LinearLayout, can it be due to that?

Comment: No. You put this attribute inside the ListView, not the parent layout.

Comment: Yes , that'w what I did , what I find in logcat is: No resource identifier found  for attribute 'style' in package 'android'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87797/discussion-between-oblivion-and-iturki).